# Restore lightweight tags after `git fetch --prune --tags`

Tags: git

I usually use `--prune` (actually `-p`) with `git fetch`. A few minutes ago, I wanted to fetch tags from a remote repository, and I did:

```
git fetch --prune --tags
```

And then *facepalm* when I saw:

```
 x [deleted]         (none)     -> opengl
```

One of my local tag, named `opengl` has been removed, and I do not see how to restore it. The [trick to restore deleted tags](http://www.baptiste-wicht.com/2011/06/git-tip-restore-a-deleted-tag/) will not work in my case, because the tag was a lightweight tag (just a reference, not a tag object).

Do you see a way to restore my tag?

---

I use git version 1.8.3.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No easy way as there's no reflogs made for tags, but perhaps you can find a backup of your `.git` directory from before the deletion.  The tag will be in either `.git/refs/tags/opengl` or in `.git/packed-refs` in the back-up.  Grab the 40-character SHA-1 and you're good to re-create it in the current repo, assuming the commit has not been garbage collected (see next paragraph).

If the tag was pointing to a commit that is not otherwise referenced (so that it has now become unreachable), `git fsck` can find the dangling commit.  You would still have to pick out the correct commit, if there are multiple dangling commits; and if the commit is reachable from some branch(es) this won't find anything useful.  But if it *is* now a dangling commit, you will probably want to restore the tag as soon as possible, to prevent `git gc` from garbage-collecting it away.