# Restore a remote branch after a `git fetch --prune`

Tags: git, git-fetch

I ran `git fetch --prune` and I see:

```
- [deleted] (none) -> origin/branch_name_here
```

I can not tell from the branch name if it was an important reference.

How do I find out where `origin/branch_name_here` was pointing?

It has not been used in a long time and so it is not listed in `git reflog`, and either way I do not know the commit message associated with `origin/branch_name_here`.

I have run `git config --local gc.auto 0` to disable garbage collection in order to prevent losing the commits.

```
git fsck --full --no-reflogs  | cut -d' ' -f3 | xargs -P2 git log --oneline | grep 'branch_name_here'
```

shows nothing because `branch_name_here` is not part of the commit message.

looking through `.git/objects/??` and sorting by file modification/creation date would take forever.

I suspect the answer is the same with respect to [pruned tags... no](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21608275/).

Comment: If the remote repository is in a hosting service like Github or Gitlab, you may find clues in the push events or pull requests/merge requests.

Comment: No, this is not a branch being deleted. This is your local repo updating the images of remote branches, and it happens that the `branch_name_here` branch no longer exists on the remote `origin`. Your local repo is now closer to what's actually on remote, this has *nothing* to do with your reflog or your local branches. If you don't `fetch --prune` often, this old branch might as well have been deleted on remote months or years ago.

Comment: @RomainValeri yes I already knew that, I sometimes keep old unused branches around for future reference, this remote branch may of been around for decades, when I was still learning about git, who knows what crazy practices I may of had when I first started learning git. So the issue remains (though it is unlikely).